# Calculating a Fraction's Reciprocal

Tags: fractions

Is there any way or equation that allows me to calculate the reciprocal of any fraction?
I mean if i have 5/6 and i need it's reciprocal by using a formula or an equation to calculate it.

Is there or not?
thanks all

Comment: $\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{-1} = \frac{y}{x} \;\; x,y \neq 0$

Comment: isn't it just f(x) = 1/x where x is that fraction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flip it, ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$ (provided the numerator is not $0$.).

The reciprocal of $\;\dfrac xy,\;\; x, y \neq 0\;\;$ is given by $\;\dfrac 1{\left(\frac xy\right)} = \dfrac yx$.

So for your fraction, the reciprocal of $\dfrac 56$ is given by $ \dfrac 65$.

Comment: so there is no specific formula or equation to calculate it?
just flipping it?

Comment: If you want an equation, then given the nonzero defined fraction $\frac xy$, it's reciprocal (also called its inverse) is given by $\left(\frac xy\right)^{-1} = \dfrac 1{\frac xy} = \frac yx$. This means whenever you multiply a fraction with its reciprocal, the answer will be $1$. The only rational number without a (mulitiplicative) inverse is $0$. You can also note that if we denote the reciprocal of $\dfrac xy$ as $r$, then we want $r$ such that $\frac xy \cdot r = 1 \iff r = \dfrac 1{\frac xy}$.

Comment: @amWhy: Another TU 4 u +1